# Generalized shape grouping macro VBA PowerPoint

Tags: vba, grouping, shapes, powerpoint

I am looking to write a generalized PowerPoint macro to group specific shapes together. The problem is I do not know the specific shape names ahead of time as my slidedeck changes slighty each time. Here is my situation: I have a collection of PowerPoint shapes whose names start with the prefix "rc". For example they could be "rc48", "rc49","rc50","rc51". They are always in increasing numerical order and the only "rc" named shapes on the slide. Following these shapes, I have a collection of shapes with the prefix "tx" (they are not the only "tx" shapes in the slide but they do always follow the "rc" shapes) and there are always an equivilant number of "tx" objects following the "rc" objects. So in this example I would have "tx52", "tx53","tx54","tx55".

What I would like to do is group these pairs of objects together. So group1 would be ("rc48","tx52"). group2 would be ("rc49","tx53") and so on.

I know very little about coding in VBA, but my approach in other programming languages would be to find the positions of the "rc" shapes in the sequential shape names vector and then count length(rcshapes_vector) past the "rc" positions to find the "tx" shapes I need and then loop over these pairs.

I realize this is a complicated question, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Working with vba code in PowerPoint is really painful because you don't have a lot of functions such as Excel vba but I hope the following ideas can help you:

You can validate the type of Shape like `If oShp.Type = msoTextBox Then` or `If oShp.Type = msoPicture Then`.

Also for each Shape you can validate the top or left property to find the position in the slide.
If you are sure your shapes have those names, maybe you can try with:

```
Dim oShp As Shape
For Each oShp In ActivePresentation.Slides(SldNumber).Shapes
   If oShp.Name = "rc49" Then
      Do Something
   End If
next
```